# Clear folder before rendering, automatically

Tags: rendering, scripting

Is there way to remove previous render files from output folder automatically before rendering?

nvm. figured it out

```
import bpy
import os

# Define the path to the folder you want to clear
folder_path = "path"

def clear_folder(folder_path):
    for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.remove(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")

# Register a function to run when rendering starts
def render_init_handler(scene):
    clear_folder(folder_path)

# Register the render initialization handler
bpy.app.handlers.render_init.append(render_init_handler)
```

Comment: You are welcome to write your script solution as an answer in the section below. You can also accept it. This way, other users who have the same problem can easily see that there is a solution.